# nginx грузит сайт из нетого конфига

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, config

Я столкнулся с проблемой на `nginx-1.13.8`:
Я добавил новый конфиг:

```
server {  
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    server_name msc.example.com www.msc.example.com;
    client_max_body_size 64m;
    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         ../cert/combinednew.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     ../cert/private_rsa.key;

    access_log logs/example.msc.access.log;
    error_log logs/example.msc.error.log warn;

    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://192.168.200.4:80;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

С каких-то неизвесних мне причин, после перезагрузке `nginx` стал загружать веб-сайт из предидущего конфига.
Ето понятно по логам:

```
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:13 +0200] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 3101 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:13 +0200] "GET /Themes/Manas/css/responsive.css?fin20 HTTP/2.0" 200 2765 "https://msc.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:13 +0200] "GET /Themes/Manas/css/index.css?fin20 HTTP/2.0" 200 15622 "https://msc.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:13 +0200] "GET /Themes/Manas/scripts/theme.js?fin20 HTTP/2.0" 200 1417 "https://msc.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:13 +0200] "GET /Themes/default/css/smf_snowflakes.css?snow5 HTTP/2.0" 200 482 "https://msc.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:13 +0200] "GET /Themes/default/scripts/script.js?fin20 HTTP/2.0" 200 13077 "https://msc.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:13 +0200] "GET /Themes/default/scripts/jquery.snow0.js?snow3 HTTP/2.0" 200 705 "https://msc.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:13 +0200] "GET /Themes/default/scripts/jquery_3.3.1_min_snowflakes.js?snow3 HTTP/2.0" 200 30309 "https://msc.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:13 +0200] "GET /Themes/Manas/images/collapse.gif HTTP/2.0" 200 125 "https://msc.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:14 +0200] "GET /Themes/Manas/images/custom/flat-bg.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 168670 "https://forum.example.com/Themes/Manas/css/index.css?fin20" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:14 +0200] "GET /Themes/Manas/images/expand.gif HTTP/2.0" 200 126 "https://msc.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:14 +0200] "GET /Themes/Manas/images/theme/main_block.png HTTP/2.0" 200 320127 "https://forum.example.com/Themes/Manas/css/index.css?fin20" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
[11/Feb/2019:23:08:14 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" 404 244 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
```

К тому-же, ето `forum.*.log` файл, когда `msc.*.log` файл пуст.

Кто может помочь с решением етой проблемы?

**nginx.exe -V**:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.13.8
built by cl 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc=cl --builddir=objs.msvc8 --with-debug --prefix= --conf-path=conf/nginx.conf --pid-path=logs/nginx.pid --http-log-path=logs/access.log --error-log-path=logs/error.log --sbin-path=nginx.exe --http-client-body-temp-path=temp/client_body_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=temp/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=temp/fastcgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=temp/scgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=temp/uwsgi_temp --with-cc-opt=-DFD_SETSIZE=1024 --with-pcre=objs.msvc8/lib/pcre-8.41 --with-zlib=objs.msvc8/lib/zlib-1.2.11 --with-select_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-mail --with-stream --with-openssl=objs.msvc8/lib/openssl-1.0.2n --with-openssl-opt=no-asm --with-http_ssl_module --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_module
```

Comment: Лучше бы посмотреть error.log и вывод nginx -V

Comment: А вы уверены что в вашем conf/nginx.conf подключен новый конфиг? И выключен старый.